# Why can't JavaScript dictionary keys start with a number using the myDict.123 syntax?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, programming-languages, language-design, identifier

#### Preface

The answer to this question may very well be "because the creators of JavaScript decided so."  Mostly I'm just curious if there's a specific reasoning behind this decision, aside from mere consistency with other identifiers/variable names and other languages.

#### Question

This is legal:

```
var foo = { "1abc": "bar", 1: "lol" };
document.write(foo["1abc"]);
document.write(foo[1]);
```

Lines 2-3 of this are not legal:

```
var foo = { "1abc": "bar", 1: "lol" };
document.write(foo.1abc);
document.write(foo.1);
```

I have not used a language where identifiers can start with a number, but until JavaScript, I also have not used a language where dictionary values could be referenced using both `dict[index]` and `dict.index` syntax.

I'm not sure if dictionary keys are considered identifiers or not.  If they are, then this question is a no-brainer.

Then again, I'm not really clear why JavaScript identifiers can't start with a number, given that numbers are a Number type.  In other languages (e.g. C#) numbers have types like `int`, `long`, `double`, etc causing `5L` or `5D` to specify "5 as long" and "5 as double" respectively.  So, in theory, JavaScript identifiers *could* start with a number, and be fine (I think).

C#:

```
var x = 5L; // x is long type
var y = 5D; // x is double type
```

JavaScript:

```
var x = 5L; // syntax error
var y = 5D; // syntax error
```

So, my guess is that JavaScript identifiers can't start with a number for consistency with other languages, and JavaScript dictionary keys can't be referenced with `dict.123` syntax for consistency with other JavaScript identifiers.  Is this the only reason?

Comment: JavaScript identifiers cannot begin with a numeric digit character. The `.` operator requires that the right-hand operand is an identifier. That's all there is to it.

Comment: @Pointy That's what I figured.  Do you know if there's a reason why JS identifiers can't start with a number besides consistency with other languages?

Comment: there's good reason for "consistency". you should ask yourself: why other languages don't allow it?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I did, and I explained why, at least in C#, in my question.

Comment: It simplifies the grammar by removing ambiguities, and probably because it's so common among widely-used programming languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you answered your own question.  "because the creators of JavaScript decided so."

From msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/67defydd%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

Lastly, what you are dealing with are object literals, not dictionaries.  Javascript has two ways of retrieving member properties for different occasions.  "." syntax is for static access, "[]" is for dynamic access.  Consider the following:

```
var myObj = {
  x:"foo",
  getX: function() {return this.x;}
};

var get = "get";
var X = "X";
alert(myObj[get+X]());  //Alerts "foo";
```

Javascript lets you do some pretty dynamic things, that usually result in horribly unmaintainable code, but its still pretty cool.